# Reusing a database table for many other entities? Is this possible?

Tags: database

Say for example, I have an `ADDRESS` table, that will store similar attributes of other entities like `address, city, zip, country,` etc. The entities are `USER, COMPANY, BANK, BRANCH,` etc. I would like to use this one table `ADDRESS` to store the addresses of the other entities rather than creating other tables for each entity to store the `ADDRESS` like so, `USER_ADDRESS`, `COMPANY_ADDRESS, BANK_ADDRESS, BRANCH_ADDRESS`.

Is this possible? Am i breaking any laws or conventions? What are the consequences, if any?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each entity (`USER`, `COMPANY`, etc.) should contain a *reference* to an entry in the `ADDRESS` table.

There are a few issues:

- If 2 users have the same address, they should reference the same address id.
- You will need to normalise addresses so that you're not duplicating information (e.g. if you know the city, then you automatically know the zip and country).
- Of course, you may not want a well-normalised database. Saving the entire address as a string will improve read performance by reducing the number of `join` operations.

A lot of things depend on the exact use of the database.

Comment: This is wrong. If two users have the same address, they shouldn't have the same address ID. If one of them moves you're editing the address for everyone that lives there.

Also, knowing the city you don't automatically know the ZIP. Most cities have different ZIP codes for different areas. If you know the ZIP and the country you can infer the city. Different countries can use the same ZIP code.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use a single `ADDRESS` table for that purpose and have an `ADDRESS_ID` in each of the other entities. Depends on the use case and the way you prefer to implement it. I most probably wouldn't do it. I also wouldn't do the other solution you're suggesting (an address table per entity).

So, let's say you want to implement a function to search for all the addresses, where it doesn't matter what type of entity is connected to it. You will have to search the `ADDRESS` table. If you get results, then you have to search the other four tables to see which record is connected to that address.

You could add a field `ENTITY_TYPE` in the `ADDRESS` table where you specify which type of entity it is connected to, so you don't have to search the four tables, but I don't recommend this since you can have consistency errors (`USER 17` points to `ADDRESS 14`, but `ADDRESS 14` has `ENTITY_TYPE = BANK`).

Now, with your other solution (having four separate tables to store the addresses of the four different entities) you're just going to have to search those four tables and then search the corresponding entity table to get the entity you're looking for.

My solution in most cases is adding the address fields to the entities tables themselves. Having `ADDRESS`, `ZIP_CODE` and `COUNTRY_CODE` (always use proper country codes, not country names https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) will make it simple. When you present a list of items (users, banks, companies, offices, whatever), it's really common to show the name and the address at the same time in a table. Having no JOINS makes it faster and easier to process. If you want to update an address, it's on the table itself. No lookups!

Of course, like most things in programming, it depends on what your needs are.

Also, please, don't try to split the `ADDRESS` in more fields. I've seen `ADDRESS_TYPE` (street, road, avenue, square, ...), `STREET_NAME`, `STREET_NUMBER`, `BLOCK_NUMBER`, `BLOCK_FLOOR`, `BLOCK_LETTER`. I'm pretty sure you're never going to need something like `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE STREET_NUMBER = 74`.